# Backbone deep cloning issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Ok, so I have deep cloned a model in backbone:

```
this.parent.views[card_id].previousModel = $.extend(true, {}, this.model);
```

As you can see, I am keeping a copy of my subviews in the parent view, and before I change a subview's model I am making a deep clone of this model and storing it under 'previousModel'.

Now, strange things happen when I access this later on.

So if I log out the previous and present model ,as such:

```
console.log( this.parent.views[this.model.get('card_id')].previousModel );
console.log( this.model );
```

I can drill down into these and everything as would be expected, the attributes of previousModel are different to those of this.model. And if I log out, say the date attributes I have:

```
console.log( this.parent.views[this.model.get('card_id')].previousModel.get('departure_date') );
console.log( this.model.get('departure_date') );
```

This is all ok - in the console I see:

```
29-09-2013
28-09-2013
```

This is as expected as the action I took after saving previousModel was to change departure_date.

Here's the weird stuff. I also have another field, departure_timestamp. If I look at this attribute by drilling down through the logged model I see this in previousModel:

```
departure_timestamp: 1380409200
```

and this in this.model:

```
departure_timestamp: 1380322800
```

All good. But then if I try and access these as I had departure_date, by using the get method, I see this:

```
console.log( this.parent.views[this.model.get('card_id')].previousModel.get('departure_timestamp') );
console.log( this.model.get('departure_timestamp') );

1380409200 
1380409200
```

Why is this different from when I access departure_date using the same method? I've even gone so far as to log out the two models again after using the get method to make sure that nothing is changing the value of departure_timestamp inbetween, and no, nothing. The values are different as expected.

So, what is different here using the get method? My first thought was that deep cloning didn't clone the methods in some way and I was still referencing the original model, but then this would surely mean I would see the same result when using the get method to access departure_date?

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I don't think `$.extend(true, {}, this.model)` is a good way to deep clone a Backbone model instance, you'd probably be better off using `JSON.stringify` on `this.model.toJSON()` and `JSON.parse` to unpack that into a new model. `$.extend` is for simple nested data structures but there's more to a model than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - just set a load of console.logs throughout my code to trace the run of play. It seems that the timestamps are being set at the end of everything. The confusion has been through seeing the correct results in the console, but I need to remember that the console is not always giving a real-time true evaluation of atributes. I obviously need to tighten up my code and make sure things happen when they should.